# Hibernate EventListener, access to entity deprecated / removed. Bad design, or are there alternative solutions?

Tags: hibernate

I'm updating from 5.4.14 to 5.4.33 (the latest version in 5.4, in preparation for moving to 5.6 shortly). In our code base we make use of event listeners, specifically `PreUpdateEventListener` and `PreInsertEventListener` to implement various checks before things are persisted.

In these implementations, we sometimes grab the entity instance and manipulate it directly. For example via `PreInsertEvent#getEntity`. This has worked very well for many years.

In 5.4.33 (but probably earlier, but not in 5.4.14) `getEntity` is now deprecated with the comment

`Support for JACC will be removed in 6.0`

My questions

- What is JACC?
- Is it considered poor/bad design to access an entity instance directly in these event listeners, or are there alternative ways you can implement similar functionality? As far as I can see the only information you will be provided going forward is the entity *class* and the object state as an `Object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by re-writing our event listeners as JPA listeners instead, thereby removing the direct dependency on Hibernate altogether.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).